# Synchronizing Live via MIDI

Tags: ableton-live

I would like to  synchronize an Analog Four MKII & Analog Rytm with Ableton Live 9 using a focusrite 2i/4 ..

1.- Connecting the MIDI out of your Focusrite to the MIDI in on Elektron Analog Four

2.- Connecting the audio out of the hardware device to the input on your audio interface switched to Inst.

3.- Connecting the MIDI sync. out A of Elektron Analog Four to the MIDI in port on Focusrite Scarlett 2I4

Then I don't have any MIDI port left on the focusrite, But I have a Sync Out B in the Elektron Analog Four that I guess I have to connect it to the MINI In of the Analog Four MKII, right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Focusrite->Analog Four MKII->Analog Rytm

Use the MIDI Thru on the Analog Four MKII connected to the MIDI In on the Analog Rytm.

Alternatively, just get a USB hub on the computer, and connect to the USB connection on both devices. Keep the Focusrite on it's own USB connection (not on the hub), and use it to drive your output devices (headphones/amps etc)